# Extending of ShellHeadItem (render?)

Tags: javascript, sapui5, render, extend

I need to add the item into shell. This is done using ShellHeadItem, but I don't want it to be an icon, but button with a text.

I am able to change the span child in html but the framework is refreshing the shell after few seconds or after first click on the button. I am trying to eliminate this "flickering" (it is visible) with call of functions for changing it again to text, but it is not perfect..

Could you please direct me to how should I extend the object and I think it's render object? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "shell", I assume you are referring to the SAP "[ushell](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ushell)" also known as the Fiori Launchpad shell. SAP's API documentation in the UI5 SDK is not very comprehensive, but there are some things you can do to achieve what you want within the SAPUI5 public methods.

First, you want to wait until the shell has rendered. SAP has some provided boilerplate code for returning a Promise that will achieve that (note- this is provided code when you create a plugin app from the Fiori Plugin template via the Web IDE):

```
  _getRenderer: function() {
        var that = this,
            oDeferred = new jQuery.Deferred(),
            oRenderer;

        that._oShellContainer = jQuery.sap.getObject("sap.ushell.Container");
        if (!that._oShellContainer) {
            oDeferred.reject(
                "Illegal state: shell container not available; this component must be executed in a unified shell runtime context.");
        } else {
            oRenderer = that._oShellContainer.getRenderer("fiori2");
            if (oRenderer) {
                oDeferred.resolve(oRenderer);
            } else {
                // renderer not initialized yet, listen to rendererCreated event
                that._onRendererCreated = function(oEvent) {
                    oRenderer = oEvent.getParameter("renderer");
                    if (oRenderer) {
                        oDeferred.resolve(oRenderer);
                    } else {
                        oDeferred.reject("Illegal state: shell renderer not available after receiving 'rendererLoaded' event.");
                    }
                };
                that._oShellContainer.attachRendererCreatedEvent(that._onRendererCreated);
            }
        }
        return oDeferred.promise();
    }
```

This promise returns the [shell renderer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Renderer/properties) which you can use to add an item to the header beginning or end of the toolbar. The two methods you'll want to pay attention to are "addHeaderEndItem" and "addHeaderItem". There are instructions in the SDK that lay out how to use it, but I think the easiest way to understand implementation is to see my example below:

```
        var rendererPromise = this._getRenderer();
        rendererPromise.then(function(oRenderer) {
            oRenderer.addHeaderEndItem(
                "sap.ushell.ui.shell.ShellHeadItem",
                {
                    icon:"sap-icon://action",
                    press: that._buttonPress.bind(that)
                },
                true,
                false,
                [oRenderer.LaunchpadState.App, oRenderer.LaunchpadState.Home]
            );
        });
```

You can read the shell renderer API (above) for more information on what each of the settings is, but a couple words of caution.

First, make sure you are putting this in an "onInit" of either the Component (init) or a view's controller to avoid adding multiple times. The most preferable option is adding it as a plugin if you are using the SAP Cloud Platform Portal service to manage your Fiori Launchpad.

Second, don't use the "addFloatingButton" method yet. It is not ready. I won't go into detail but let's just say I put a bunch of hours into debugging the SAP prototypes and they have a bug or two deep in there.

Lastly, take into account when you need this button. The array at the end of the add method contains enums "App" and "Home". From SAP:

> The launchpad states that can be passed as a parameter. Values: App - launchpad state when running a Fiori app Home - launchpad state when the home page is open

Hopefully that makes sense, because I can't articulate it better than that :)

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for insight on the wait for rendering of the shell. I haven't been trying to use extensions in either Eclipse or WebIDE, because Eclipse wasn't working with importing of the shopping cart application and I lost my nerve. And I havent used web ide because we hadnt had it connected to servers.

So because of that I just added some scripts to the FioriLaunchpad.html and had it like that.

Now we have WebIDE, I am using it for extending other application, but haven't tried to use it for /UI2/USHELL.  Should I? 

I know about adding items, but i wanted add more custom f.e. text.

Comment: And yes, I am talking about sap.ushell.ui.shell.ShellHeader. I just use the onAfterRendering event and I am changing the content of the html. Because otherwise I'd have to change the renderer of the Whole Shell I think.

Comment: And in the /UI2/USHELL in our version, there is no Component.js, so in WebIDE there is no extension posibility I think.

Comment: @Dalton - You don't have to use an extension or plugin to utilize the renderer promise I provided. All it does is ensure that the launchpad shell is rendered completely before you modify anything.

Comment: I would not recommend trying to extend the ushell in the WebIDE. 

Changing the content of the html with jquery,etc can be tricky because you are going outside the SAPUI5 framework and therefore will have elements that might render incorrectly, destroy incorrectly, etc. 

Again, I would recommend using the Shell Renderer methods in the link I provided in my original answer whenever possible.

Comment: Yes, I will consider changing this, because I found out, that when I resize the window, it rerenders and causes prolblems in rendering.

Answer (score 1):

So I used this

```
var oShellHeader = sap.ui.getCore().byId("shell-header");
oShellHeader.addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function () {
        // ... change the html
    }
})
```